# String to method (invoke) throws an Exception

Tags: java, string, invoke

I want to call a method, given a String. I mean, I have a String which is the name of the method I want to call.

I've seen that the reflection is the way to meet the target but, when I try to get the method (before invoking it), I get an exception.

That's what I have done:

```
        Method method = Object.class.getMethod("functionToCall", String.class);
```

Why is this command throwing an exception? What can I do in order to get the method which is going to be invoked?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The `Object` class has no method called `functionToCall` which takes a `String` as parameter. What did you expect to be returned by this? Didn't you want to put your own class which actually has a `functionToCall` method instead of `Object` there?

Comment: I think you took the instructions a tad too literally.

Comment: Also, when you get an exception, you should include the exception in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying in your example is to get the `functionToCall` method which takes a `String` as parameter from `java.lang.Object` class. It won't happen.

However you can use `getMethod()` and the `invoke()` combination like this:

The class to work with:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(final String pString) {
        System.out.println("Hello "+pString);
    }
}
```

And to actually invoke the method

```
// We get the method myMethod which takes a String.
Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod", String.class);
// We call it on a new MyClass instance with "Test" as parameter.
method.invoke(new MyClass(), "Test");
```